# Defining dictionary inside a class in python

Tags: python

I am creating an empty dictionary inside a class and then I am trying to give the variables inside the dictionary some value. As shown in the code below. In the end, I am trying to print the dictionary values in the console but I receiving errors

In the editor:

```
import numpy as np
class A:
    def __init__(self, variables = {}):
        self.variables = {}
        if ("leng") in variables:
            self.variables["leng"] = variables["leng"]
        else:
            self.variables["leng"] = np.array([10,])


        if ("width") in variables:
            self.variables["width"]= variables["width"]
        else:
            self.variables["width"] = np.array([10,])
```

In the Console:

```
variables.items()


>>>"leng" : 10
>>>"width" : 10
```

Comment: `variables` doesn't exist, your argument is called `variable`, singular. It's also a [mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument), which you probably don't want

Comment: what error are you getting? full traceback please. What is `variables`?

Comment: Variables is my dictionary which is initially empty but later I initialize two keys in it called 'leng' and 'width' . I am trying to print my dictionary in the console

Comment: Where are you doing `print(variables.items())`? *Inside* the class, or *Outside* of it? Because once you get outside the class, the variable goes out of scope - you'd then need to create an instance  `a = A(vars)` and then `print(a.variables.items())`.

Comment: This seems like a vague problem. Are you calling the class via an instance? By instance, I mean an object of the class, like m=A() and then m.variables

Answer (score 0):

Just use an object to call class items.

`m=A()` and then `m.variables`